# Comparing Graphs (LineCharts)

Tags: python, math, graph

I am trying to compare a set of Graphs. [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M85Jx.png) I want to compare all the "thin" printed Graphs to to "thick"( -GoalGraphs) ones.

**The Data** 
- All the Data is slightly different in lenght and amplitude (see below)

> Graph a: [315,92,60,46,36,33,29,28,26,24,23,22,20,21,19,19,18,17,18,17,16,17,16,16,17,16,16,17,16,17,16,17,15,17,16,17,16,17,17,16,16,16,16,17,17,16,17,16,16,16,15,16,17,17,16,16,17,16,17,16,17,16,16,17,16,16,16,16,17,16,17,16,17,18,16,18,18,18,18,19,19,20,20,23,30,40,56,69,62,59,55,59,66,78,79,75,84,77,72,73,79,83,86,586]
>
> Graph x: [302,88,56,45,38,34,30,28,25,25,22,22,20,20,18,19,17,18,17,16,17,16,16,16,16,16,16,15,16,17,16,16,17,16,16,17,16,16,16,16,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,17,17,17,18,17,18,19,19,19,20,23,27,37,49,69,64,61,56,55,60,71,79,75,78,87,73,75,78,79,81,590]

**The Goal** - I want to check if the shape of to "thinner" Graphs is the same as of the "thicker" Graphs. So even if the position of DataPoints do not match correctly i want the algorithm to recognise the Pattern.

**Solutions**

1. I read about interpolating the thicker Graphs and comparing them to the others. I could find a Solution to Interpolate the Graph [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#id3) but i couldn't found out how to campare it to other Graphs. I am also not sure if this would match a Graph where DataPoints are "missing" (e.q. The Grap is shorter then the Goal Graph)
2. I tought about Maschin Lerning or Pattern Recognition and i tried to find some good stating Points but the field is huge.
3. Mentioned by Yakov Dan i tried

> import numpy as np
>
> array_a = [315,92,60,46,36,33,29,28,26... ]
>
> array_b = [302,88,56,45,38,34,30,28,25... ]
>
> print(np.correlate(array_a,array_b,'valid'),'valid')
>
> which results in [578559] valid

Can you Explain what the Result is standing for?

**The Question:** - What is the best way to do this? Could someone give me a hint where to start, or how to solve this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Start with normalizing the amplitude of each graph, then compute pairwise cross correlation.

Suppose you have `array_a` and `array_b`, which contain data that you want to compare. you can cross-correlate them using numpy, like this:

cc = np.correlate(array_a,array_b,mode='full').

cc is a `vector`, not a value. What cc contains is the similarity between `array_a` and a **shifted** version of `array_b`. `cc[0]` contains the similarity between `array_a` and `array_b` when `array_b` is shifted by 0, `cc[1]` contains the similarity between `array_a` and `array_b` when `array_b` is shifted by 1,
`cc[2]` contains the similarity between `array_a` and `array_b` when `array_b` is shifted by 2, etc... for all possible shifts when there is an overlap between `array_b` and `array_a`

See if you can take it from here

Comment: pairwise correlation will not solve the problem since i would not find out if the pattern matches. If a high in one graph starts earlier then in the other they will not match

Comment: Yes it will. Cross correlation is not very sensitive to phase difference.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation

Comment: I Tried to CrossCorreleate the mentioned arrays with numpy.correlate (a PythonLib) but i do not understand what the Data is showing will update the question.

Comment: Ahh much thx for this explanation, but i think this is not what i am looking for. If you loook at the Plot und focus und the last 4 Lines u will see that  the "thinner" Graphs miss some Values, though yet as Human i can see they have the same shape as the thicker ones. if i just shift the arrays the graphs will not match. For better explanation: I will always compare ech thin graph with the "brown - thick one. (Yes the aplitudes are normalized, its just the representation)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the answer to a similar question. I don't know if the question still stands for the OP but I will share what I got so far.
You need to have some fixed points for comparison. Like in a human's case you could take the plotted graphs and overlap them looking through a light desk. You would try to match the bigger patterns.
My approach, though expiremental at best was
-divide you sequence into smaller parts. Define such parts as points where your lines change direction, a sign change in the function if you can handle mathematical explanation more. Where the function turns from ascending to descending or vice versa

-Those parts will have a max and min and also because they a single change of sign they can be approximated with a polynomial equation of(apparently at the moment) grade five.

-get the domain you are working in. Remember as a human you would overlap using the most proeminent point (max). You need to redristibute the domain. If previously you went from [0,n) now 0 becomes the max value

-normalize your data. Basically divide all the data to the max value

-get the quoeficients for the equation. You can get it through curve_fit from scipy. Optimization.

-after this step for each segment you have all the quoeficients for the generic equation of each segment.
-to check if the new lines inputed are similar to the thick ones you just need to see if
1)they have similar number of parts
2) if each part's domains are similar
3)if each part's coefficients are the same or similar

Each of these points either eliminates a curve from comparison or will give percentages in similarity.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always support your answer with output obtained using provided. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for guidance.